# Finding similar names and getting average of them

Tags: r, numbers, duplicates

```
 name      reading
 1201_a     24
 1201_b     25
 1301_a     12
 a_1201_01  12
 a_1201_02  14
 a_1201_03  26
 b_1301     25
```

I have a table like this where I need to get average of the reading if they have the same starting name. In this table I want to take an average of the reading `1201_a` and `1201_b`; `a_1201_01`, `a_1201_02`, and `a_1201_03`, but I want to have the same reading if the file is unique, here `1301_a` and `a_1301`. I know I can't do duplicate as the name is not exactly same. Please guide me how can I write R-code for this purpose.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(group = gsub('_.{,2}$', '', name)) %>% summarise(reading = mean(reading))`?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, .(reading = mean(reading)), .(name = sub("^([a-z])_(\\d+).*", "\\2_\\1", name))]
#     name reading
#1: 1201_a      19
#2: 1201_b      25
#3: 1301_a      12
#4: 1301_b      25
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(name = c("1201_a", "1201_b", "1301_a", "a_1201_01", 
"a_1201_02", "a_1201_03", "b_1301"), reading = c(24L, 25L, 12L, 
12L, 14L, 26L, 25L)), .Names = c("name", "reading"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```